# Calling an input in another php file

Tags: php

I have two php files;

- The first is a table that has a thumbnail image, title and a text input, so the user can enter a price. I have just used a simple `<input name="price" type="text">`
- The second file, structures the an email that is sent to me, also a table and pulls the title of the item from the first php file. But i cannot get it to pull the content from the text input. `<td scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $_POST["price"]; ?></td>` does not work.

I have also tried in the first php file, `$price = $_POST["name"]` and then `<td scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $price; ?></td>` in the second php file, to no luck.

I am sure this has been asked and answered before but everything I have found and tried hasn't worked.

---

I am sending by POST, i have took a plugin from Yith for woocommerce called Request a quote and i am adapting it, so the user doesn't change the quantity of the item but put a price in the text box.

```
<form id="yith-ywraq-form" name="yith-ywraq-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( YITH_Request_Quote()->get_raq_page_url( 'update' ) ) ?>" method="post">

<td class="product-quantity"> <input name="price" type="text"></td>
```

then on the second php file i have:

```
<tr>
  <td scope="col" style="text-align:left;">
    <a href="<?php echo get_edit_post_link( $_product->id )?>">
      <?php echo $_product->post->post_title ?>
    </a>
    <?php  if( isset($item['variations'])): ?>
      <small><?php echo yith_ywraq_get_product_meta($item); ?></small>
    <?php endif ?>
  </td>
  <td scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $_POST["price"]; ?></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Are you sending by POST or GET the form? Share your code, without it we can't help you. The code you need to share: the HTML with the `<form>` tag, the PHP receiving data.

Comment: We need to see how you send the price to PHP.  How does the user submit price? How are the two files linked?

Comment: have you used method="post " in your form?

Comment: And the right way is to use $_POST["price"] not $_POST['name'];

Comment: i have added to the original question, it pull everything else from the first php except the $_POST["price"]

Answer (score 0):

I would check two things:

First: Is whatever the browser submits actually what you want it to submit?
Second: Is what the server gets processed in the way you'd expect?

(My guess is the first)

For the first one:
Open the form page in question, press f12 (firefox/chrom*, don't know about opera, but I guess it's the same there) and switch to the network tab, send the form and look at the params of the post request, if there's really all the values.

If it already fails there, you have to fix your HTML. Since the code sample you provided is quite small, I can only guess, that you don't close the form or that it's invalid in a way, that the browser doesn't understand what actually belongs to the form. Don't start forms between `<td>`s for example.

If your browser in fact DOES submit the correct data, you should provide more information about your php scripts that lay behind

```
esc_url( YITH_Request_Quote()->get_raq_page_url( 'update' ) )
```

if there is some kind of actual browser-redirection, this problem get's more complicated.

Comment: thanks for this, i opened the network tab and sent the form, it post fine but the amount i typed into the input box does not appear in the params.

Comment: as I said, you have to fix your html form in that case ... which means, if you want more help, provide more html code, and don't cut it down into oblivion.